# How can i fix a 'Command' is not defined error

Tags: discord.js

I tried many things to fix it, but nothing worked for me. I am using discord v12 to code.

The whole error is just: 'Command' is not defined. I also do not get any errors in console.

So, the question is: How do i define Command?

The code is for a !warn command

Here is the code:

```js
client.on("message", message => {
    let Discord = require("discord.js")
    let client = new Discord.Client()
    const ms = require("ms")
    const config = require('./config.json');
    var msg = message.content.toUpperCase();
    
    class Warn extends Command {
      constructor(client) {
        super(client, {
          name: "warn",
          description: "Command om een gebruiker te waarschuwen",
                usage: "warn",
                category: "System",
                permLevel: "Moderator"
            });
    }
```

Below here is the rest of the code, but i dont think thats neccesary

Comment: Is this a self-made command handler? I would suggest you research a guide on discord.js before attempting to create a bot.

Comment: It seems you've already asked this here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65644880/typeerror-class-extends-value-command-is-not-a-constructor-or-null-node-js You should add more details there instead.

Answer (score 0):

Nowhere have you defined command; You want to include `client.commands = new Discord.Collection();` somewhere in your code, id recommend looking through the [discord.js guide](https://discordjs.guide), as this stuff is covered there

Comment: OP has an undefined `Command` class, not an undefined `commands` property on `client`.